# What is bogofilter, and do I need it?

Tags: software-recommendation, uninstall

I am trying to thin out the applications and processes on my computer. To do this, I am going through the pack lists in synaptic. I got to bogofilter, which says its a wordlist spam filter. I am not using the MTA programs, that Ubuntu came with, and may even uninstall them if it won't break my system.

That said, can I remove bogofilters and not break my system?
Ubuntu mate 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is Bogofilter?

As you have rightly understood, [bogofilter](http://bogofilter.sourceforge.net/) is a mail filter that classifies emails as spam or ham (non-spam) by a statistical analysis of the message's header and content (body).

> Can I remove bogofilters and not break my system?

I see no problem in uninstalling Bogofilter. If you uninstall bogofilter you will not mess up Ubuntu. Sometimes bogofilter can come (or can be) integrated with  email clients such as Claws Mail, KMail, Evolution, etc. and other mail deliver agents. So if you uninstall it you may lose that functionality. That said, at least Evolution doesn't come integrated with bogofilter (instead, I think Evolution uses SpamAssasin)